# Exception Signal 11 using JNI CallBooleanMethod

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I 'm getting a SIGNAL 11 in this line:

```
// Call bool isInternetConnection()
jboolean jReturnValue = env->CallBooleanMethod(mClass,mid);
```

in this piece of code:

```
/**
 * Check if Internet Connection is ONLINE
 */
bool InterfaceJNI::isInternetConnected()
{
    JavaVM* jvm = JniHelper::getJavaVM();
    int status;
    JNIEnv *env;
    jmethodID mid;

    bool isAttached = false;
    bool returnValue = false;

    CCLog("InterfaceJNI isInternetConnected");

    // Get Status
    status = jvm->GetEnv((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    if(status < 0)
    {
        CCLog("isInternetConnected Status < 0 Failed to get JNI Enviroment!!!");
        status = jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
        CCLog("isInternetConnected Status 2: %d", status);
        if(status < 0)
        {
            CCLog("isInternetConnected Status < 0 !!!");
            return false;
        }
        isAttached = true;
        CCLog("isInternetConnected Status isAttached: %d", isAttached);
    }

    CCLog("isInternetConnected Status: %d", status);

    CCLog("isInternetConnected Finding Class....");
    jclass mClass = env->FindClass("org/example/SocialNetwork/CCSocialNetwork");

    // Get Static bool isInternetConnection()
    CCLog("isInternetConnected Getting method....");
    mid = env->GetMethodID(mClass, "isInternetConnection", "()Z");
    if (mid == 0)
    {
        CCLog("isInternetConnected FAIL GET METHOD STATIC");
        return false;
    }
    CCLog("isInternetConnected Calling method....");
    // Call bool isInternetConnection()
    jboolean jReturnValue = env->CallBooleanMethod(mClass,mid);
    CCLog("Call done ");
    // Convert value from Java to C++
    returnValue = (bool)jReturnValue;
    CCLog("isInternetConnected Done ");

    if(isAttached)
        jvm->DetachCurrentThread();

    // Change for return value
    return returnValue;
}
```

But I don't know why. If I make a void call with a "()V" works fine, but when I try to call a function which return a bool no.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a static method or not? Your comments in the code indicate that it is static while your method calls do not.

If it is *NOT* static then you will have to call the `CallBooleanMethod` with an object and not the class like you do now. Otherwise you will have to use `CallStaticBooleanMethod` with the class.

```
jobject someObject = <get or create the object somehow>
jboolean jReturnValue = env->CallBooleanMethod(someObject,mid);
```

*OR*

```
jboolean jReturnValue = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(mClass,mid);
```

Either way you will have to decide whether to use static methods or not.

Comment: It is not a static method. I Tried before using Static method, but I had the SIGNAL BUS problem as you know, so, I changed my Java function and now is non-static. The point is, What object is requested by the function?

Comment: The object needed is the object to run the method on. `someObject.isInternetConnected()` in Java.